# Distance in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that for all $u,v \in V(G),$ if $f:G \rightarrow H$ is homomorphism, then $d_{G}(u,v) \geq d_{H}(f(u),f(v)).$

Comment: Do you mean graph homomorphism? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  How is the distance (in $G$) from $u$ to $v$ defined?  What becomes of this when the (graph) homomorphism $f$ is applied?  Mere statement of a problem, without any evidence that the problem statement has been digested, may suggest to Readers a lack of interest on your part.

Comment: A homomorphism f from G to H is a function f : V (G) → V (H)
which preserves edges; that is, if xy ∈ E(G), then f(x)f(y) ∈ E(H).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_0 =u , u_1 , \dots ,u_n = v$ be a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$.

Then $f(u_0) , \dots, f(u_n) $ is a path from $f(u) $ to $f(v)$ in $H$.

This yields $d_G(u,v) \ge d_H(f(u),f(v))$.

Comment: is there any reason for the down vote?

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/3q1xev.jpg

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout lol, im not sure if you're against \ pro the down vote

Comment: @infinty I am against the down vote, and I also know very little graph theory.

Comment: Oh, ok :)  @cansomeonehelpmeout

Comment: It's generally frowned upon (by some people) to post answers to low-quality questions like this, where no effort is shown by the poster (it's better to ask for them to show some work, or to vote to close the question).